# Service plan migration for SQL DB

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to migrate from SQL DB small plan to premium plan? Assume we have started with the small plan and data exceeds 10GB. Can the plan be migrated to premium? If yes, does this include data movement?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there's no way to automatically migrate your data.  You have to manually migrate from the small to the premium plan.  You should be able to use the SQL Database console to manually export your data, then once you've subscribed to the premium plan, you should be able to load the data via the SQL DB Console as well.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Database console does not have ability to import/export data. To move data from one SQLDB instance to another, consider to use the Bluemix DataWorks Data Load REST API.
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/index-gentopic1.html#task_d4j_q1r_np

Alternatively, you may also create a Bluemix app so you may import and export data from/to SQL Database service:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-sqldb-app/

Comment: SQLDB instances created under the Free plan do not support Import/Export. But instances created under the Small or Premium plan do. So it is possible to migrate from a Small to a Premium using the import/export tools, but what you are saying here is correct if moving from Free to one of the Paid plans.